# Custom Validation if textbox is empty but data still to record in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

This My aspx i want when i insert data is not to record in database...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description" class="control-label">Hazard Description : </label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="55" Rows="7"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorHazardDescription" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server"  Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Tidak Boleh Kosong" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorHazardDescription_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I Clik insert message successfull but data still to record in database?
 This My code behind i want when i insert data is not to record in database...

```
protected void CustomValidatorHazardDescription_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     TextBox txb = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("TextBox3");


     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txb.Text))
     {

         args.IsValid = false;                       
      }
         else
      {
         args.IsValid = true;
         return;
       }
}
```

This Process insert

```
        tbl_hzr_main newitem = new tbl_hzr_main();
        newitem.code_company = int.Parse(((CustomControls_DdlCompany)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("ddl_company1")).SelectedValue);


        newitem.code_empPIC = int.Parse(((HiddenField)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("hid_pic_id")).Value);
        newitem.code_hzrUser = id_spv;
        newitem.code_incdLocation = int.Parse(((CustomControls_DdlLocation)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("ddl_location1")).SelectedValue);
        newitem.code_main_contractor = int.Parse(((CustomControls_DdlCompany)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("ddl_company1")).SelectedMainConValue);
        newitem.code_section = code_section;
        newitem.code_usrEntry = int.Parse(uc.usrID);
        newitem.date_hzrMain = DateTime.Parse(((TextBox)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text);
        newitem.desc_hzrMain = ((TextBox)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox3")).Text; // this insert to database  


        newitem.dueDate_hzrMain = DateTime.Parse(((TextBox)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox2")).Text);
        newitem.entryDate_hzrMain = DateTime.Now;
        newitem.folup_hzrMain = ((TextBox)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox4")).Text;
        newitem.locDetail_hzrMain = ((TextBox)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("txb_loc_detail")).Text;
        newitem.PICsign_status = byte.Parse(((RadioButtonList)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("rbl_sign_pic")).SelectedValue);
        newitem.stat_hzrMain = byte.Parse(((RadioButtonList)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("RadioButtonList1")).SelectedValue);

        dbcontext.tbl_hzr_main.Add(newitem);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you shows does anything with a database. Can you show the code where you insert the data (and where you supposedly check first if data is valid before inserting)?

Comment: ok sir, already to add.

Comment: simply enclose the whole "Database Save" code inside if(Page.IsValid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnSubmit function or Button_Click event (Where form Submits) add

```
Page.Validate();
 if (Page.IsValid == true){
//Add to Database
}else {
//Dont Add to Database
}
```

Comment: Great this is i want

Answer (score 1):

from you updated question, below this line :

```
newitem.desc_hzrMain = ((TextBox)_f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox3")).Text; // this insert to database
```

try adding this code :

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(newitem.desc_hzrMain)){
   //show alert or something that data fail to insert
   return;
}
```

Comment: Good for only one field but if more validations are needed it would be exhaustive

Comment: Good advise @Hannan